# Flex: adding an element to a linked XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, hyperlink

Take the following code, we have 2 XMLs, the first contains some data that we will link to the second. After doing that, if I want to add an element to the first XML, it gets added to the second XML, and only the second XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" initialize="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void
            {
                var xml1:XML =  <xml1>
                                    <data>
                                        <element id="1"/>
                                    </data>
                                </xml1>;

                var xml2:XML =  <xml2>
                                    <data/>
                                </xml2>;

                trace("xml1:");
                trace(xml1);
                trace("xml2:");
                trace(xml2);

                trace("-------------");

                xml2.data.appendChild(xml1.data.children());

                trace("xml1:");
                trace(xml1);
                trace("xml2:");
                trace(xml2);

                trace("-------------");

                xml1.data.appendChild(<element id="2"/>);

                trace("xml1:");
                trace(xml1);
                trace("xml2:");
                trace(xml2);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

The expected outcome would be:

```
xml1:
<xml1>
  <data>
    <element id="1"/>
    <element id="2"/>
  </data>
</xml1>
xml2:
<xml2>
  <data>
    <element id="1"/>
  </data>
</xml2>
```

Or perhaps:

```
xml1:
<xml1>
  <data>
    <element id="1"/>
    <element id="2"/>
  </data>
</xml1>
xml2:
<xml2>
  <data>
    <element id="1"/>
    <element id="2"/>
  </data>
</xml2>
```

But the outcome here is:

```
xml1:
<xml1>
  <data>
    <element id="1"/>
  </data>
</xml1>
xml2:
<xml2>
  <data>
    <element id="1"/>
    <element id="2"/>
  </data>
</xml2>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting, but I'm not satisfied that I understand it completely.

XML is a true object in Actionscript. So when call `xml1.data.children()` you're getting back a reference to an XMLList object.

This XMLList then gets added to `xml2`. It's a reference to same node as before, so when you modify it we'd expect all the references to get updated.

This is what I'm unsure about:  A XML node can only have one parent. So when you add the nodes from `xml1` to `xml2` something is getting lost.

One solution, is to copy the nodes then add the copy, rather than the original reference, to `xml2`:

```
var copy:XMLList = xml1.data.children().copy();
xml2.data.appendChild(copy);
```

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right: When appending the child node (it's only one at that point) from xml1 to xml2, the hierarchy is broken.  You can verify this by adding `trace( xml1.data.children()[0].parent().parent() );`- it will return xml2! It is indeed best to append a copy, or create a new element with identical values.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it even better. One of the many reasons I'm so addicted to StackOverflow now :)

Comment: Yes, I also already used the copy trick but wanted to know why this is happening.